# Stitching image tiles of the same size, with different offsets/positions

Tags: image, tile, image-stitching, mosaic

I have ~200 images (scanned map extracts) that I would like to stitch into a single large image

All images are of the same width/height (~3000 x ~1900px), however, they do not stack above/below/beside eachother neatly - Basically they all need to be manually positioned by eye, so that features in the images align with their neighbors

I'm hoping to post-process the final image into a bunch of square tiles that can be used with something like OpenMaps

Is there any off-the-shelf software that can assist with this? Hugin seemed like a good match at first, but I can't seem to find away to turn off its "smarts" to allow me to manually position all the images

Comment: There is no code? My question is how to approach stitching the images first

Comment: You can use **Photoshop** either automatic, or manual. For automatic, open 3-4 images that should join, then click `File->Automate->Merge`, then select `Open files` and click `Start`. To do it manually, load 2 images and set the *Blending Mode* of the top image in the *Layers* window to `Difference` and press `v` to move the image - when you get to the correct position, the overlap will go black because the difference between the images is zero when aligned.

Comment: Turn off `Snap to Grid` et al.

Comment: @Mark I had no idea photoshop had that capability! Thank you very much, the Automate->PhotoMerge option does exactly what I needed.

Comment: Excellent! It is actually easier to select multiple photos that should stitch in **AdobeBridge** and then choose `Tools->Photoshop->PhotoMerge` but it works the same - just seeing what should stitch is simpler in Bridge.